# App not installed after signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

I'm trying to install my signed apk, generated from Android Studio 1.5.1, 
I can not understand why the `release` version I can not install it, I set `debuggable` to `false`, I have only one `MainActivity` in the `Manifest.xml`, all looks ok, but the .apk do not install, anyone can explain to me why?

P.S

I uninstalled the debug version of my phone

Comment: Why don't you set it to true and see if it installs?

Comment: I've tried but nothing, and is the wrong way!

Comment: Are you installin the debug version or the release  version?

Comment: You have to locate where the artifact of your release version is and install it onto your device,  because when you hit run, it installs the debug variant onto your device even though you don't have to explicitly declare the debug build type.

Comment: I generate signed apk in the source folder, so I copy and paste it on my phone and launch installer but it doesn't install

Comment: Try the adb tool to install your apk instead and see if it installs

Comment: By copy/paste do you mean you drag/dropped it?

Comment: Where did you drop it to? Is it an emulator or is it your actual device? I don't think it is as simple as drag/drop for your phones file system but I could be wrong.

Comment: It's a real device @zgc7009 i drag the apk for test and release it on Play Store

Comment: Like I said, cd into the location of your apk, and use the adb tool to install it instead

Comment: What @Dummy said (explained in further detail by Anshul Jain it appears)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've solved by launch:

```
adb uninstall my.package.id
```

The app was already uninstall but the data had remained somewhere

Comment: while uninstalling the application, the data also gets removed. I wonder why in your case it still existed.