# Android Studio - show debug error on signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, error-log

In my app I have a strange issue - app is running correctly when I start it from AS, but when I generate signed apk and instal it manual - app crashes in 2nd activity. Is it possible to receive error log? I'm using toasts to localized this issue but this is like looking for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137719/app-not-installed-after-signed-apk follow the steps

Comment: If you connect your phone by usb with the ADM (Android device Monitor) you are able to see the log, or directly in AS in the android monitor

Comment: You can see the logcat of your device.  With a connected phone, either run `adb logcat *:E` from command line, or you can do it with android studio and "connected devices".

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) . It's a free crash reporting tool, you just have to install the Fabric plugin in Android Studio, and it'll set up everything for you.

Of course, as advised in comments, on the short term, you can still connect you phone and see the crash in logcat, but Crashlytics is a longterm solution, that'll work even when you'll not have physical access to the device, like when you publish the app on the store.

Comment: If you are targeting Android only and want a more TNO (trust no one) approach [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) is an alternative